# Error in unique.default(x) : unique() applies only to vectors in R

Tags: r, csv, plyr

```
retail_sorted <- retail[order(retail$customer_code),]
library(plyr)
itemList <- ddply(retail,c("customer_code","date"), 
                   function(df1)paste(df1$article_batch, 
                   collapse = ","))
```

when i am trying to load this it shows 'Error in unique.default(x) : unique() applies only to vectors'

can anyone help me out..

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(retail)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(retail, 20))`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and give a [mcve]!

Comment: Also, try `df1[["Description"]]`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas   the dataset is like::                                                      "bill_no","store_id","sale_date","article_id","article_batch","quantity","selling_price","tax","discount","cost_price","customer_code"
485451,3,2018-04-02,2,"T2-877",4,8.33,1.05,0,6.77246,39567
486106,3,2018-04-03,2,"T2-877",3,8.33,1.0533,0,6.77246,10677
486367,3,2018-04-04,2,"T2-877",1,8.33,1.04,0,6.77246,7315
486367,3,2018-04-04,2,"T2-877",1,8.33,1.04,0,6.77246,7315

Comment: Please read my first comment again. Don't use comments to post data, like this it's not usable. Edit **the question** with the output of `dput(retail)`. Also, there are no columns `"CustomerID"` and `"Date"` in what you have in the comment.